# Can I use Docker for production deployment of a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, web-deployment, production-environment

I want to use Docker to deploy my Rails application. I want to know if there is someone tried this? And what problems can I face?

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/rails/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deploying Rails apps to production with Docker is not only possible, but something you'd want to do, to make sure your app runs on any server you deploy.

This comes with some challenges. First, it's advisable to run your database server and your Rails app different containers to keep things isolated. You can also set up your production server Docker environment with Docker Machine. Machine allows you to configure AWS, Digital Ocean, Azure and Compute Engine instances ([among many others](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/)), and manage your containers from your computer. I assume you're just getting started with Docker, so I suggest you take a look at [this cool guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/) about setting up a Rails + Postgres app with Docker.